# Rails 3 - select tag - onchange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, view

I am trying to do select box, where after select some option value will be this value send. Now I have following

```
<%= select_tag "action", options_for_select([ "1", "2", "3"]) , {}, 
             :onchange =>remote_function(:url => {:action => :index, :id => 0 }, 
             :with => "'action='+ +this.options[this.selectedIndex].value") -%>
```

and getting error **wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)**. What is there wrong?

**EDIT:** Can anyone help me please with any function demo or example of form with select, that works with **:onchange** event (e.g. what should be in controlller)?
I still can't find the right way how to do. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the third argument `{}`.

Comment: but - how I should to set up the `form_tag`? I am a bit confused with path to controller and action

Comment: Are you wanting the whole form to submit or is this the only element?

Comment: just this element... now I haven't `select_tag` covered in `form_tag`